# Getting a NullPointerException when testing a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing

I am new to testing with Spring Boot, and am currently trying to make a simple test run.

The method I want to test is:

```
public class DigipostSpringConnector {

@RequestMapping("/test")
public String test(){
    return "Hello";
}
```

The test class I have written so far is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DigipostSpringConnector.class)
@WebAppConfiguration

public class DigipostSpringConnectorTest {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception{
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new DigipostSpringConnector()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getHello() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/test"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("Hello")));
    }

}
```

However, I get a NullPointerException when I run the test, the exception appears on the following line:

```
mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/test"))
```

It seems like the field MockMvc mvc-field is not being initialized.

What could be going wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you put `= MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new DigipostSpringConnector()).build();` on the field?

Comment: Thank you! :) That actually worked! Can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: I can't remember the specifics, but the `@Before` annotation does something special and it apparently wasn't being ran. In any case, glad that helped

Comment: @user3257736 - Just out of curiousity, which Before annotation are you using. Can you please share the import statement?

Comment: I was using: import org.junit.Before; :) Perhaps that was wrong?

Comment: I had the same error. For me it was forgetting to add the test annotations to the class `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@WebMvcTest(SomeController.class)`